# Selecting columns by regex in Hbase scanner via Thrift (in Ruby)

Tags: ruby, hbase, thrift

The [docs](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/thrift/doc-files/Hbase.html#Fn_Hbase_scannerOpenWithStop) suggest I should be able to pass a regex as a column qualifier.

I have a columns named "F1:I" and "F2:I" in the column family "C".  Consider the following:

```
columns = ['C:F1:I']
scanner = hbase.scannerOpen('myTable', startKey, columns)
```

All the "F1" rows are returned.  I had hoped to be able to pass in a regex.  I've tried variations of the following:

```
columns = ['C:F.*']
scanner = hbase.scannerOpen('myTable', startKey, columns)
```

Nothing.

Comment: Well, you didn't pass a regex, you passed a different String. Try `columns = [/C:F.*/]`.

Comment: Yeah... I know I didn't pass an actual regex.  I tried that too.  The docs suggest that I referenced show passing in `Text` so I hoped it had a forgiving way of matching column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to HBase committer Lars George, the current version of the thrift service does not support this.  The documentation referenced above is misleading.

The next version of thrift is expected to support these scenarios better.